# No sound in Lubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, 17.10

I recently installed Lubuntu onto my Chromebook after flashing the ROM with the RW-legacy firmware mod from johnlewis.ie. I had realized though that when I tried to play a video I would get no sound out of the laptop speakers. I already have Pavucontrol installed, but my speakers were not in the list of output devices. I think it might be a driver issue, but does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.